# Call object from function environment in R

Tags: r, environment

I have a function similar to this one:

```
function.mean.prod<-function(my.df,my.title){
  tmp.df<-data.frame(Year=1901:2099,Productivity=NA)
  for(i in 1:199)tmp.df[i,2]<-mean(my.df[,,i],na.rm=T)
  ggplot(tmp.df)+
    geom_line(aes(tmp.df$Year,tmp.df$Productivity))+
    ylab("Productivity in g/c/qm")+
    xlab("Year")+
    ggtitle(my.title)
}
```

Executing it i get:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'tmp.df' not found
```

So my interpretation of this error message is that the object `tmp.df` is created temporarly inside the functions environment and when the functions executes the loop it can't call the object.

is that correct?
How can I set up the environment so that the function is able to call it inside the loop?
Many thanks.

Comment: your `aes` should be: `aes(Year, Productivity)`. That is, remove the `tmp.df$` inside aes and try again.

Comment: worked. thank you. You could post it as an answer maybe mentioning that my interpretation is incorrect ;)